# rails 4 : use of form_for , no route, POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

started learning Ruby on Rails via Lynda - very excited and am trying my best to practice as much as possible. I am following the exercises but training is based on Rails 3 - through now some of the uses are not accepted.

Here is the situation:

I am reaching the create form at subjects/new
Filling out the form
get the following error in return

> No route matches [POST] "/subjects/create"
>
> Rails.root: /Users/alpozenalp/Sites/simple_cms

I spent the last 2 hours wandering around stackoverflow, rail guide and all other sources - tried many variations but can't get past this stage.

your help will be greatly appreciated.

routes.rb

```
SimpleCms::Application.routes.draw do

root :to => "demo#index"
get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'

end
```

subjects_controller.rb

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

def index
list
render('list')
end

def list
@subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")
end

def show
@subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
end

def new
@subject = Subject.new
end

def create
# Instantiate a new object using form parameters
@subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])
# Save the object
if @subject.save
# If save succeeds, redirect to the list action
redirect_to(:action => 'list')
else
# If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
render('new')
end
end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subject new">
  <h2>Create Subject</h2>

  <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :method => :post) do |f| %>

    <table summary="Subject form fields">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Visible</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Create Subject") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have completed the course and my route.rb looks like below:

```
Cms2::Application.routes.draw do  

root to: "public#index"
get 'admin', :to => 'access#menu'
get 'show/:id', :to => 'sections#show'
get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'  

post "admin_users/update"
post "subjects/update"
post "pages/update"
post "sections/update"

post "subjects/destroy"
post "subjects/create"

post "pages/destroy"
post "pages/create"

post "sections/destroy"
post "sections/create"

post "admin_users/destroy"
post "admin_users/create"

post "access/attempt_login"

get "access/logout"

end
```

My controller for def create is as follows:

```
    def create
#new_position = params[:subject].delete(:position)
# Instantiate a new object using form parameters
@subject = Subject.new(params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible, :created_at, :updated_at))
# Save the object
if @subject.save
  #@subject.move_to_position(new_position)
  # If save succeeds, redirect to the list action
  flash[:notice] = "Subject Created."
  redirect_to(:action => 'list')
else
  # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
  @subject_count = Subject.count +1
  render('new')
end
end
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 3):

naomik's answer will definitely help the form be cleaner, but it sounds like you just need to add a route for subjects in your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
SimpleCms::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :subjects    
  root :to => "demo#index"

end
```

More info in the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Edit: Removed the default fallback route, per naomik's suggestion.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the fallback route for a newbie. That's seriously old-school Ruby on Rails stuff. If the OP is just getting started with Rails 4, I'd get them started on the right foot.

Comment: naomik: that's a good point. But, that was already in the route file the OP posted above. I just added the `subjects` resource

Comment: thanks a lot - but after removing the fallback route now i get
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SubjectsController#show
Couldn't find Subject with id=show

Extracted source (around line #13):
11
12
13
14
15
16
          
  
  def show
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def new

Rails.root: /Users/alpozenalp/Sites/simple_cms

Comment: so its trying to route to subjects/id=show or id=list whereas the route should be subjects/show , subjects/list 
any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure. The "Couldn't find subject" means you're maybe trying to view or edit something that isn't there? I'm not sure. But honestly, from the code you're given, I'm not sure the Lynda course is very good. For a better, and free (the online book version is - but there are some paid videos or printed books that are not free), tutorial I'd suggest taking a look at this one (that's always kept up to date): http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: well the route for a POST should be in the form of :controller(/:action just like GET. I just can't figure out where the problem is

Comment: Hmm. Still not sure what the problem is. Did you 1) add the route I suggested `resources :subjects`, and 2) adjust the form like naomik mentions in her answer? With the entry in your routes file, and the updated form, Rails will figure out the `/subjects/create` stuff for you, and you won't need to hardcode the create (or update) action.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have any problem if you just do

```
<%= form_for @subject do |f| %>
```

The `form_for` helper will automatically choose the correct (idiomatic) `action` and `method` based on the state of the model.

If `@subject` is a new record, you will get

```
<form action="/subjects" method="post">
  ...
```

If `@subject` is an existing record (with id: 1), you will get

```
<form action="/subjects/1" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
  ...
```

---

**Extra:** Your `list` action seems completely pointless. Just use the `index` as intended.

Then this piece of code

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-link') %>
```

Becomes this

```
<%= link_to '&laquo; Back to List'.html_safe, subjects_path, class: 'back-link' %>
```

Comment: And `<% form_for` need to be` <%= form_for`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem at this point in the Lynda.com course. It was solved by adding `resources :subjects` above `get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'`, then changing the subjects_controller `create` action to

```
def create
    @subject = Subject.new(params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible))
    if @subject.save
        redirect_to(:action => 'list')
    else
        render('new')
    end
end
```

This circumvented the Forbidden Attributes Error that occurred with the action as it was previously written.

Because I'd added `resources :subjects`, this then meant the `redirect_to(:action => 'list')` above would create an error along the lines of 'Couldn't find Subject with id=list'. To fix this, I added `get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#list'` above the `resources :subjects` route (I've no idea if this was the 'right' thing to do, but it works for now).